# I have a question about WordPress websites my all WordPress websites are slow and I am frustrated with it

Tags: wordpress

I am a developer and I will create many websites for client and I have the same issue with all websites, websites are very slow and nothing big file on the website and it's still slow. Even four five-page websites are slow. I am using the nulled plugin it is possible to a nulled slow website.

I will optimize images and js but nothing difference.

Comment: There's many reason can cause this problem. Other than images and js files, your hosting could be slow, too much plugin can make it slow, badly written themes can cause it to slow too.

Comment: Thank you for your reply, my hosting is dedicated and it is not too much plugin on the website and I use the jnews theme if anything happens with nulled plugins?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Use optimization plugin like Autoptimize plugin. Also, add GZIP compression and leverage your browser's caching rules into the htaccess file(Below the code).

```
<IfModule mod_deflate.c>
  # Compress HTML, CSS, JavaScript, Text, XML and fonts
  AddOutputFilterByType DEFLATE application/javascript
  AddOutputFilterByType DEFLATE application/rss+xml
  AddOutputFilterByType DEFLATE application/vnd.ms-fontobject
  AddOutputFilterByType DEFLATE application/x-font
  AddOutputFilterByType DEFLATE application/x-font-opentype
  AddOutputFilterByType DEFLATE application/x-font-otf
  AddOutputFilterByType DEFLATE application/x-font-truetype
  AddOutputFilterByType DEFLATE application/x-font-ttf
  AddOutputFilterByType DEFLATE application/x-javascript
  AddOutputFilterByType DEFLATE application/xhtml+xml
  AddOutputFilterByType DEFLATE application/xml
  AddOutputFilterByType DEFLATE font/opentype
  AddOutputFilterByType DEFLATE font/otf
  AddOutputFilterByType DEFLATE font/ttf
  AddOutputFilterByType DEFLATE image/svg+xml
  AddOutputFilterByType DEFLATE image/x-icon
  AddOutputFilterByType DEFLATE text/css
  AddOutputFilterByType DEFLATE text/html
  AddOutputFilterByType DEFLATE text/javascript
  AddOutputFilterByType DEFLATE text/plain
  AddOutputFilterByType DEFLATE text/xml

  # Remove browser bugs (only needed for really old browsers)
  BrowserMatch ^Mozilla/4 gzip-only-text/html
  BrowserMatch ^Mozilla/4\.0[678] no-gzip
  BrowserMatch \bMSIE !no-gzip !gzip-only-text/html
  Header append Vary User-Agent
</IfModule>

## EXPIRES CACHING ##
<IfModule mod_expires.c>
ExpiresActive On
ExpiresByType image/jpg "access 1 year"
ExpiresByType image/jpeg "access 1 year"
ExpiresByType image/gif "access 1 year"
ExpiresByType image/png "access 1 year"
ExpiresByType text/css "access 1 month"
ExpiresByType application/pdf "access 1 month"
ExpiresByType application/javascript "access 1 month"
ExpiresByType application/x-javascript "access 1 month"
ExpiresByType application/x-shockwave-flash "access 1 month"
ExpiresByType image/x-icon "access 1 year"
ExpiresDefault "access 2 days"
</IfModule>
## EXPIRES CACHING ##
```

Comment: Thank you for your reply, it works but increases some speed my yslow score is 52% and the average score is 71% can you please suggest any more thing about speed

Comment: Use autoptimize plugin for more page speed. Please refer its document for how to optimize CSS and js from autoptimize plugin. And also exclude js which are not working after this plugin activating.

Comment: is autoptimize plugin conflict with smush pro by WPMUDEV because I have used for smush pro for image optimization?

Comment: Ok, So you can exclude the smush plugin folder on the autoptimze plugin. read this post maybe it's work for you https://wordpress.org/support/topic/exclude-entire-plugin/